# Missing highlight in Google Email Markup

Tags: google-schemas

I've been working on google email markup for few weeks now. I've submitted it for review. The google review team replied that the mark up is missing highlight in it. About the markup, the email is about Schedule confirmation which gets sent to the patient from hospital. The email contains schedule date, time, doctor name and hospital name. I've used Event Reservation JSON/LD. The markup testing tool shows everything is correct. There is no mention of highlight on the following link
[Event Reservation Reference](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/event-reservation)

Here is the JSON/LD for reference

```
{
  "@context":              "http://schema.org",
  "@type":                 "EventReservation",
  "reservationNumber":     "12345",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "underName": {
    "@type":               "Person",
    "name":                "John Doe"
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type":               "Event",
    "name":                "Schedule Appointment",
    "performer": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "image": "www.mysite.com"
    },
    "startDate":           "2020-08-21T10:00+05:30",
    "location": {
      "@type":             "Place",
      "name":              "Viman Nagar",
      "address": {
        "@type":           "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress":   "Viman Nagar",
        "addressLocality": "Viman Nagar",
        "addressRegion":   "Viman Nagar",
        "postalCode":      "Viman Nagar",
        "addressCountry":  "Viman Nagar"
      }
    }
  },
  "modifiedTime":"2020-08-21T10:00:00+05:30",
  "modifyReservationUrl":"www.mysite.com"
}
```

The above JSON/LD does not show any error on mark up test tool. I've entered every mandatory and suggested data in the JSON. How to specify highlight in it? I could not find any reference to highlight in the above mentioned link.

I'm also attaching the screenshot of the email I received during testing on Google App Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid Date format in the your `startDate` property. Please find the corrected JSON below:

```
{
  "@context":              "http://schema.org",
  "@type":                 "EventReservation",
  "reservationNumber":     "12345",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "underName": {
    "@type":               "Person",
    "name":                "John Doe"
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type":               "Event",
    "name":                "Schedule Appointment",
    "performer": {
      "@type": "Person",
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "image": "www.mysite.com"
    },
    "startDate":           "2020-08-21T10:00:00+05:30",
    "location": {
      "@type":             "Place",
      "name":              "Viman Nagar",
      "address": {
        "@type":           "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress":   "Viman Nagar",
        "addressLocality": "Viman Nagar",
        "addressRegion":   "Viman Nagar",
        "postalCode":      "Viman Nagar",
        "addressCountry":  "Viman Nagar"
      }
    }
  },
  "modifiedTime":"2020-08-21T10:00:00+05:30",
  "modifyReservationUrl":"www.mysite.com"
}
```